# ogrinfo SQL GROUP BY Clause

Tags: sql, ogr

Does `ogrinfo` support a *GROUP BY* clauses? I could not find any good documentation of all the SQL syntax features it supports.

I tried the following:

```
ogrinfo . -geom=no -sql 'SELECT lsad FROM tl_2011_us_county GROUP BY lsad'
```

And got the following error:

```
ERROR 1: SQL: Failed to parse SELECT statement, extra input at BY token.
INFO: Open of `.'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
```

What I really want to do:

```
SELECT lsad, count(*)
FROM tl_2011_us_county
GROUP BY lsad
```

What I can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT lsad
FROM tl_2011_us_county
```

And then:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM tl_2011_us_county
WHERE lsad = 'foo'
```

... but that is annoying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on the datasource - if OGR needs to fall back to [OGR SQL](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_sql.html) (like when using shapefiles) then no.  But if you are using PostGIS for instance you can use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I am in a catch 22 then. I wanted to inspect the shapefiles before I insert them in my postgis table, but to do it conveniently, I must insert them into a postgis table. Oh well. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking at group by clause in `ogrinfo`/`ogr2ogr` try using -dialect sqlite option:

For example:

```
ogr2ogr -dialect sqlite -f CSV "output.csv" "input.shp" -sql "select field1,sum(field2) from input group by field1 order by field1" -lco SEPARATOR=SEMICOLON
```

Above will convert shape file to csv (without geometry), separated by SEMICOLON and using group by clause of sql.

Comment: This is the correct anwer. It works when querying a shapefile (of course really a dBaseIII + geometry) and that is what the OP wanted; I happen also to be helped by this answer.